# How to correctly clone elements in jQuery (which will work in IE7 and 8)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've together a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynhya/) of how I'm trying to clone elements according to a dropdown value selection, however it doesn't work in IE7 and 8 (shows "null" instead of the cloned element). Can anyone see how to correct this? Many thanks. The JS code is as follows:

```
 // Dropdown select
$('#quantity').live("change", function(){

    $('.questions_clonable:not(:first)').remove();

    // Get value of selection
    var num = $(this).val();

    var cloned_el = $('.questions_clonable').clone();   

    if (num > 1)
    {  
        for (var i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {
            // Assign cloned block to new var
            var new_block = cloned_el;  

            // Bit of a workaround needed to clone properly, reiterating class name
            $('.multiple_questions_container').append('<span class="questions_clonable hidden">'+new_block.html()+'</span>');

        }   
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not support the CSS :not selector so to get it done

change this

```
$('.questions_clonable:not(:first)').remove();
```

to

```
$('.questions_clonable:not(.questions_clonable:first)').remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynhya/5/)